# Delete a iptables chain with its all rules

Tags: linux, iptables, linux-networking

I have a chain appended with many rules like:

```
> :i_XXXXX_i - [0:0]
> -A INPUT -s 282.202.203.83/32 -j i_XXXXX_i 
> -A INPUT -s 222.202.62.253/32 -j i_XXXXX_i 
> -A INPUT -s 222.202.60.62/32 -j i_XXXXX_i 
> -A INPUT -s 224.93.27.235/32 -j i_XXXXX_i 
> -A OUTPUT -d 282.202.203.83/32 -j i_XXXXX_i 
> -A OUTPUT -d 222.202.62.253/32 -j i_XXXXX_i 
> -A OUTPUT -d 222.202.60.62/32 -j i_XXXXX_i 
> -A OUTPUT -d 224.93.27.235/32 -j i_XXXXX_i
```

when I try to delete this chain with:

> iptables -X XXXX

but got error like (tried iptables -F XXXXX before):

> iptables: Too many links.

Is there a easy way to delete the chain by once command?

Comment: I've not seen iptables barf like that before when trying to flush.

Comment: Just curious... *how* many rules is "many" ?

Comment: 2 many is many :) if I try to delete the rules first, it will like typing many times: iptables -D OUTPUT -d XXX/32 -j i_XXXXX_i

Comment: Try this: `iptables-save | grep -v i_XXXXX_i | iptables-restore`

Comment: @StevenMonday why not write as answer, this is the most useful one (alternative do this via file and edit file).  Only thing it does not remove is complete tables ("raw" anyway)

Comment: @StevenMonday You ingenious bastard!  This is the best answer here! ♥

Answer (score 53):

You can't delete chains when rules with '-j CHAINTODELETE' are referencing them. Figure out what is referencing  your chain (the link), and remove that. Also, flush then kill.

> -F, --flush [chain]
>
> Flush the selected chain (all the chains in the table if none is given).  This is equivalent to deleting all the rules one by one.
>
> -X, --delete-chain [chain]
>
> Delete the optional user-defined chain specified.  **There must be no references to the chain.**  If there are, you *must delete or  replace  the
>   referring  rules*  before  the  chain can be deleted.  The chain must be empty, i.e. not contain any rules.  If no argument is given, it will
>   attempt to delete every non-builtin chain in the table.

Comment: I just want to find a way to delete the chain(has many '-j CHAINTODELETE' ref rules) directly, but from your answer, it seems impossible :(

Comment: @timy StevenMonday's comment will single-pass remove any references to the chain. Perhaps not ideal, but darned close.

Comment: Works like a charm.

iptables -nvL|grep "^Chain.*0 references"|awk '{print $2}'|while read LINE; do iptables -X $LINE; done

Answer (score 20):

This is potentially off-topic, but it's what I did after I found this post!
For some use cases the iptables -D  option might be useful. Since it allows you to clear out referring rules added programmatically with -A (if you know precisely how you added them).

E.g

```
    iptables -N MYCHAIN
    iptables -A INPUT -i interface -j MYCHAIN
    iptables -A MYCHAIN -j ACCEPT
```

can be reversed with

```
   iptables -D INPUT -i interface -j MYCHAIN
   iptables --flush MYCHAIN
   iptables -X MYCHAIN
```

Answer (score 16):

You need two steps, but this does it in **one** command.

Create a file, and place this in it.

```
# Empty the entire filter table
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
COMMIT
```

Save the file as "clear-all-rules".  Now, do this command:

```
iptables-restore < clear-all-rules
```

Now you can clear it anytime with just one command.

Comment: +1 This is actually the fastest way to start with a clean fw config.

Answer (score 12):

Here's an alternate plan. It involves three commands, not one, but with luck, it should work.

Dump your `iptables` ruleset to a file:

```
iptables-save > /tmp/iptables.txt
```

Remove ALL uses of (and references to) the offending chain:

```
sed -i '/i_XXXXX_i/d' /tmp/iptables.txt
```

Then reload the ruleset:

```
iptables-restore < /tmp/iptables.txt && rm /tmp/iptables.txt
```

Answer (score 5):

In the iptables man file there is an option `-S`

> S, --list-rules [chain]
>                 Print  all  rules  in  the selected chain.  If no chain is selected, all chains are printed like iptables-save. Like every other iptables
>                 command, it applies to the specified table (filter is the default).

By using `iptables -S | grep <CHAINNAMEHERE>`. For examples:

> root@root:~# iptables -S | grep TRAFFICLOG
>
> -N TRAFFICLOG
>
> -A FORWARD -i eth0 -j TRAFFICLOG

you can then see which rules are blocking the deletion of the chain from the table. Go through each rule (except the `iptables -N <CHAINNAMEHERE>` and delete the rule by using the `-D` option

> -D, --delete chain rulenum
>                 Delete  one  or more rules from the selected chain.  There are two versions of this command: the rule can be specified as a number in the
>                 chain (starting at 1 for the first rule) or a rule to match.

For example `iptables -D FORWARD -i eth0 -j TRAFFICLOG`. After you have deleted each rule for your chain flush the chain with the `-F` option, `iptables -F <CHAINNAMEHERE>`.

> -F, --flush [chain]
>                 Flush the selected chain (all the chains in the table if none is given).  This is equivalent to deleting all the rules one by one.

Then delete your chain with the `-X` option, `iptables -X <CHAINNAMEHERE>`

> -X, --delete-chain [chain]
>                 Delete  the  optional  user-defined chain specified.  There must be no references to the chain.  If there are, you must delete or replace
>                 the referring rules before the chain can be deleted.  The chain must be empty, i.e. not contain any rules.  If no argument is  given,  it
>                 will attempt to delete every non-builtin chain in the table.

Iptables is a complicated tool set so an ideal tutorial is needed. You can try one out at [www.iptables.info](http://www.iptables.info)

Comment: This helped a lot because flush cleans the chain itself but not the references to it in the other chains.

Answer (score 0):

Something along these lines will get all of them in a single line without taking iptables down in any way.

```
for chain in `iptables -L |grep i_XXXXX_i|awk '{ print $2 }'`; do iptables -X $chain; done
```

Answer (score 0):

This will spit out chains and delete them

```
for i in $(iptables -S | awk '{print $2}' | uniq ); do iptables -F $i && iptables -Z $i && iptables -X $i  ; done
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found that you can remove the rules and chain by editing the rules file in /etc/iptables/rules.v4. If you delete the unwanted chain in this file and then reload iptables, you should no longer see the chain when doing a iptables -L.

Comment: This file exists only on certain Linux distributions, and then only on certain _versions_ of certain Linux distributions.